# Can the static initialization order fiasco occur in C programs?

Tags: c, compiler-errors, static

When I search for static initialization order problems, I see a lot of examples in C++ that explain this problem. I wonder: can the static initialization order fiasco problem occur in C programs?

Comment: Example(s) of problems you are having???

Comment: Much less so because C does not have function-based initialisation.

Comment: Not in strictly conforming C, but some implementations have extensions that let you designate functions as initialization functions, so problems can arise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Static initialization in C does not have the same problems that C++ has.

In C, objects with static storage duration may only be initialized via constant expressions, i.e. values that can be computed at compile time, so there are no issues that can arise regarding order of initialization.

In contrast, C++ allows calling functions to initialize static objects, and the order in which those functions are called are not well-defined.